# Can't add custom font to HTML/CSS website template

Tags: html, css

So I got a template from bootstrap and I've been working on it for a few days.. (I'm new to HTML/CSS). I can't seem to add a custom font for the life of me. My fonts are placed in a folder called 'fonts'. My css files are divided into 'main.css' file and 'fonts.css' file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
```

```
/*In MAIN.CSS file 
====================*/

.home-content h1 {
    font-family: "sharpgrotesk-bold", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 6rem;
    line-height: 1.35;
    margin-top: 0;
}

/*In FONTS.CSS file 
====================*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "sharpgrotesk-bold";
    src: url("fonts/SharpGrotesk-Bold20.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Check inside your browser developer tools for 404 errors. You'll probably see an error for loading `fonts/SharpGrotesk-Bold` which will tell you which path your browser is trying to fetch. Note that `url()` in css requires you to pass **relative paths** to the css file itself (fonts.css), unless they start with "/" in which case they are absolute. So your current url() assumes the "fonts" directory is inside the same directory as fonts.css (inside your css folder).

Comment: @dirkgroten OMG!! Ty!! I dont know why I didn't think of that!! just added '../' to URL. I'm new to this man.. (1 week) Tnx for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check inside your browser developer tools for 404 errors. You'll probably see an error for loading `fonts/SharpGrotesk-Bold` which will tell you which path your browser is trying to fetch.

Note that `url()` in css requires you to pass **relative paths** to the css file itself (fonts.css), unless they start with "/" in which case they are absolute.

It's good practice to use relative paths, because that way you don't have to change your urls when you deploy to production (and maybe change the root location of all your static files to a CDN).

So your current url() assumes the "fonts" directory is inside the same directory as fonts.css (inside your css folder). If your "fonts" directory is at the same level as your css directory, then you need to go one folder up:

`src: url("../fonts/SharpGrotesk-Bold20.otf") format("opentype");`